# rsync -vvv gets stuck in OS X with no clear explanation

Tags: osx, rsync

All of a sudden (not sure when the problem started) my `rsync` commands against a given machine get stuck:

```
$ (dd bs=1024 count=1024 </dev/urandom >/tmp/temp_file && rsync -arvvv --progress /tmp/temp_file -e ssh hostname.sldc.company.net:/tmp/)
1024+0 records in
1024+0 records out
1048576 bytes transferred in 0.087832 secs (11938431 bytes/sec)
opening connection using: ssh hostname.sldc.company.net rsync --server -vvvlogDtpre.iLsfx . /tmp/  (7 args)
```

I have the same exact problem **without** `-e ssh` returning the same **exact** error (including the `ssh` bit, which I wouldn't expect)

```
$ (dd bs=1024 count=1024 </dev/urandom >/tmp/temp_file && rsync -arvvv --progress /tmp/temp_file analytics04.sldc.dataxu.net:/tmp/)
1024+0 records in
1024+0 records out
1048576 bytes transferred in 0.086265 secs (12155310 bytes/sec)
opening connection using: ssh hostname.sldc.company.net rsync --server -vvvlogDtpre.iLsfx . /tmp/  (7 args)
```

**Note**: No one else in my company has this problem, and I do **not** have this problem with any other machine either **or** with this machine and a different user name. I can also `ssh` into the machine without problem.

What can I do to diagnose the problem?

#### Platform and versions:

This is all on OS X Yosemite with:

```
$ uname -a
Darwin my_machine.net 14.3.0 Darwin Kernel Version 14.3.0: Mon Mar 23 11:59:05 PDT 2015; root:xnu-2782.20.48~5/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
```

and:

```
$ rsync --version
rsync  version 3.1.1  protocol version 31
Copyright (C) 1996-2014 by Andrew Tridgell, Wayne Davison, and others.
Web site: http://rsync.samba.org/
Capabilities:
    64-bit files, 64-bit inums, 64-bit timestamps, 64-bit long ints,
    socketpairs, hardlinks, symlinks, IPv6, batchfiles, inplace,
    append, ACLs, xattrs, iconv, symtimes, no prealloc, file-flags

rsync comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.  This is free software, and you
are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.  See the GNU
General Public Licence for details.
```

which I installed with `brew`. I also had the same problem with the version of `rsync` that comes with OS X:

```
$ rsync --version
rsync  version 2.6.9  protocol version 29
Copyright (C) 1996-2006 by Andrew Tridgell, Wayne Davison, and others.
<http://rsync.samba.org/>
Capabilities: 64-bit files, socketpairs, hard links, symlinks, batchfiles,
              inplace, IPv6, 64-bit system inums, 64-bit internal inums

rsync comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.  This is free software, and you
are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.  See the GNU
General Public Licence for details.
```

#### DTracing the command:

[This gist](https://gist.github.com/amelio-vazquez-reina/d55b6918a78d1cf76759#file-gistfile1-txt) shows the first part what I get by running the following command:

```
sudo dtruss rsync -arvvv temp_file username@XX.YY.ZZ.VVV:/tmp/
```

then immediately after the last line in the Gist above, I am asked my password:

```
username@XX.YY.ZZ.VVV's password:
select(0x6, 0x7FFF50052860, 0x0, 0x7FFF500527E0, 0x7FFF500528F8)                 = 0 0
select(0x6, 0x7FFF50052860, 0x0, 0x7FFF500527E0, 0x7FFF500528F8)                 = 0 0
select(0x6, 0x7FFF50052860, 0x0, 0x7FFF500527E0, 0x7FFF500528F8)                 = 0 0
select(0x6, 0x7FFF50052860, 0x0, 0x7FFF500527E0, 0x7FFF500528F8)                 = 0 0
```

(every ~ 60 seconds or so, a new line identical to the last one above one is printed)

Comment: why are you using rsync -e ssh when all you need is rsync -avh --progress /file username@hostname:/tmp/   -e is redundant, technically. Specially without the ''s around the -e command. Name resolution works? Ping it, nmap it

Comment: Thanks @SaulOrtega. Name resolution, regular `ssh`,  `ping` etc. definitely works. I also have the same problem without the `-e ssh` option.

Comment: Have you tried to reinstall rsync just in case?

Comment: Thanks @SaulOrtega. I tried `brew install rsync` in part to address that concern, and run into the same problem. I assume this qualifies as a clean and separate installation.

Comment: Have you tried to rsync to another working host? That might at least tell you if your problem is the connection to that specific host is bad, or if your installation of rsync is the problem.

Comment: @SaulOrtega Thanks. Yes. I mention that in the OP (I just added emphasis to make sure it's not lost between so much text).

Comment: Have you debugged it with dtruss? Also, try with just the ip address.

Comment: Thanks @SaulOrtega -- How would you go about debugging this with dtruss? `rsync` with the ip address gets equally stuck.

Comment: I gotta go but refer to this website: http://opensourcehacker.com/2011/12/02/osx-strace-equivalent-dtruss-seeing-inside-applications-what-they-do-and-why-they-hang/

Comment: Thanks @SaulOrtega I have run `dtruss` on the command, and I am seeing an interesting pattern after I am asked for my password. I have updated the OP.

Answer (score 1):

If you think the problem might be an idle connection getting closed, you might be able to work around the problem by using a `--timeout` option (newer rsyncs send keep-alive messages during lulls). You can also configure ssh to send keep-alive messages when using Protocol 2 (look for KeepAlive, ServerAliveInterval, ClientAliveInterval, ServerAliveCountMax, and ClientAliveCountMax). You can also avoid some lulls by switching from --delete (aka --delete-before) to --del (aka --delete-during).

If you can't figure out why the failure happened, there are steps you can take to debug the situation. One way is to create a shell script on the remote system such as this one:

```
#!/bin/sh

ulimit -c unlimited

# Some systems have "truss" or "tusc" instead of "strace".
# The -f option tells strace to follow children too.
# The -t option asks for timestamps.
# The -s 1024 option increases the string decoding limit per function call.
# The -o option tells strace where to send its output.
strace -f -t -s 1024 -o /tmp/rsync-$$.out rsync "${@}"
```

You would use the script like this:

```
rsync -av --rsync-path=/some/path/rsync-debug HOST:SOURCE DEST
rsync -av --rsync-path=/some/path/rsync-debug SOURCE HOST:DEST
```

This script enables core dumps and also logs all the OS system calls that lead up to the failure to a file in the /tmp dir. You can use the resulting files to help figure out why the remote rsync failed.

Comment: Thank you Saul, I will try this in the next few hours. What's also interesting is that I can `rsync` without problem with other usernames (I have updated the OP to reflect this). So odd..